# CellForRow is called with delay

Tags: swift, uikit, mapkit

I try to load data from a web server whenever the user location has significantly changed. My problem is, that with any location change the tableview calls "numberOfRows" but it waits like 30 seconds until "cellForRowAtIndexPath" is called. Or until the user has moved the table.

I also sometimes experienced random warnings that auto layout was influenced from not the main queue thread (which might be related to this problem)

Where is my Problem? Maybe I doing things 2 times async is not good?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class GroundListTVCTEST: UITableViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate
{

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var searchController    :TKSearchController!
    var localSearchRequest  :MKLocalSearchRequest!
    var localSearch         :MKLocalSearch!
    var localSearchResponse :MKLocalSearchResponse!
    var grounds:[Ground]? {
        didSet {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        let distance:CLLocationDistance = 1000.0
        locationManager.distanceFilter = distance
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        print("Location Manager started.")

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        print("Location Manager stopped.")

    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("cellForRow called")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = grounds?[indexPath.row].name
        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("number of rows called")
        return grounds?.count ?? 0
    }

    // MARK: - Delegate Methods

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        print("Location Manager updated location.")
        if let location = manager.location {
            self.locationUpdateWithNewLocation(location)
        }
    }

    func locationUpdateWithNewLocation(location: CLLocation)
    {
        GroundHelper.getAllGroundLocations(location, completionHandler: { (grounds: [Ground]?) -> Void in
            self.grounds = grounds?.sort({$0.distance < $1.distance})
        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that's because GroundHelper.getAllGroundLocations returns value in background queue.
Try to dispatch it in main queue:

```
 GroundHelper.getAllGroundLocations(location, completionHandler: { (grounds: [Ground]?) -> Void in
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.grounds = grounds?.sort({$0.distance < $1.distance})
      })  
 })
```

Comment: Yes. That is the solution. Thank you!